# I am trying to pull an attribute from list items and insert an incremented number as html in those items using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use javascript to get the numbered value from the list attribute, and add that text as html to the list items so they show in the page. Here is my original list:

```
<ol class="slideshow">
    <li data-slide="0"></li>
    <li data-slide="1"></li>
    <li data-slide="2"></li>
</ol>
```

and I want it to ultimately look like this:

```
<ol class="slideshow">
    <li data-slide="0">1</li>
    <li data-slide="1">2</li>
    <li data-slide="2">3</li>
</ol>
```

I've been wasting my time trying different things with jquery and/or javascript, so far with unsuccessful results. Seems simple to me but apparently I'm incapable. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I don't see any javascript in the question. It would help to show your attempts.

Comment: It's always good to show the code you tried, even if it doesn't work, so we know that you put at least some effort into solving your own question. Otherwise a question like this tends to look like a "gimmie da codez" demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a function to the `text()` method which you can use to read the `data` attribute. Try this:

```js
$('.slideshow li').text(function() {
  return $(this).data('slide') + 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="slideshow">
    <li data-slide="0"></li>
    <li data-slide="1"></li>
    <li data-slide="2"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, worked perfectly and I just wasn't getting it. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).data('slide') + 1);
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ph2scqzo/

Comment: Thanks man, this worked perfectly as well... just marked the first one as correct because it was up there :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var lis = $('.slideshow li');

$(lis).each(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).data('slide')  + 1);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9wefr45n/)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code to help other readers understand why and how this solution works.